# How can I call a function made in kotlin from C++ for Unreal 4?

Tags: c++, kotlin, unreal-engine4

I have this function in kotlin:

```
fun ShowCalibrationUI() {
        with(ManualCalibrationManager) {
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                launchCalibrationUI(_context, ManualCalibrationManager.Duration.THIRTY)
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to call this method from c++ for UE4.

Comment: Is kotlin even compiled? Isn’t it Java?

Comment: Generally speaking, the answer to "how to call language X from language Y" is "write a shim in C". And given that X = Kotlin and Y = C++, I don't see a better way in this case.

Comment: Alternatively, port the code to the other language.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.